# Empty Project in Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I want to create an empty project in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012, but somehow I don't see any template for that.
I go to File->New Project and the "New Project" dialog box pops up. On the left side I click on "Visual C++" but the only subitem is "Windows Store" and there is no template for an empty project. I can only see templates for creating apps.
Isn't it possible to create empty projects in the new version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably trying to use Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 **for Windows 8**. Try using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 **for Windows Desktop**. If you want to create a plain C++ project in Windows 8, this is the way to go. Confusing, I know.

Answer (score 1):

Empty Solution = Blank Solution?

File > New Project... > Templates > Other Project Types > Visual Studio Solutions > Blank Solution